# Localization resource not properly working

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

Xcode is complaining about: "GuestFlowView.swift:18:25: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report"

It seems to be linked to the user of `LocalizedStringKey` or the variable.

For example, if I replace :

```
 GuestFlowImageTab(title: title1,
                   desc: desc1,
                   image: "houseprice")
```

by

```
 GuestFlowImageTab(title: "title1",
                   desc: "desc1",
                   image: "houseprice")
```

I works because the variable name is considered as a String.

When using `LocalizedStringKey`, I use a key defined in the `Localizable.strings` as defined below:

"GuestFlowPage1Title" = "tyyuu";
"GuestFlowPage1Desc" = "nhjkhkj";

below my code.

```
struct GuestFlowView: View {
    let title1 = LocalizedStringKey("GuestFlowPage1Title")
    let desc1 = LocalizedStringKey("GuestFlowPage1Desc")
  
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                GuestFlowImageTab(title: title1,
                                  desc: desc1,
                                  image: "houseprice")
                GuestFlowFormTab()
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
           
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

It seems that my localizable file is not seen.

[image]

the strings is as below:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you select "Localizable.strings" file "Localization" to base/english and "Target Membership" to current app?

Comment: @54min it seems. added a picture

Comment: @54min so it seems that now xcode see one file for Localized but only english. `base` is not seen and the error message is still there